# VLOOKUP to count number of rows with two values

Tags: vlookup, countif

I have a spreadsheet with several rows of contact information. Column A contains dates that clients emailed us. Column H contains either 'Yes' or 'No' for whether they require a call back.

I'm trying to get a total number of callbacks required for a specific date. So find all instances of 01/11/2019 in column A, then find how many of those rows have 'Yes' in column H. I can get it to count the total number of instances of 01/11/19 and count the number of 'Yes' separately. But can't get it to just give me the total number of rows with both the 01/11/19 and Yes criteria.

The furthest I've got is combining a VLOOKUP with COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,VLOOKUP("01/11/2019",7,"Yes"))
```

which doesn't work. I based this on another StackOverflow question/solution, but it didn't really fit what I'm trying to do. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've have worked this out! Apparently VLOOKUP was completely wrong and COUNTIFS works better. My working formula is:

=COUNTIFS(A:A,"01/11/2019",H:H,"Yes")

Which returns the correct number of rows with both criteria in.